# Constructor from reference to parent class in polymorphism

Tags: c++, polymorphism

Is it possible to make constructor in derived class which receives reference of the parent class pointing to another child class?

```
Child ch;
Parent &pr = ch;
Child ch1 = pr;
```

I guess it might be something like this:

```
Child(const Parent &pr){
*this = dynamic_cast<Child>(pr);
//Invalid target type 'Parent' for dynamic_cast; 
//target type must be a reference or pointer type to a defined class
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to delegate to the `Child`'s copy constructor:

```
Child(const Parent& pr) :
    Child(dynamic_cast<const Child&>(pr))
//                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^
//              note:     const&
{}
```

If the `Parent`/`Child` relationship isn't the expected, you'll get a `bad_cast` exception.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/155orWh9M)